# In this equilateral triangle, if $AE = EF = FB$, prove $AG = GH = HB$

Tags: geometry

Consider an equilateral triangle $ABC$, with two lines $CE$ and $CF$ passing through $C$ and meeting the circle drawn with $AB$ as diameter on $E$ and $F$ respectively such that the arcs $AE, EF, FB$ formed are equal. Prove that the lines divide $AB$ into three equal parts. Specifically, prove that

$$AG = GH = HB$$

[image]

Consider $D$, the midpoint of $AB$ and the centre of the circle. Clearly,

$$\angle ADE = \angle EDF = \angle FDB$$

Also, by symmetry, it is worth noting:

$$\angle ACG = \angle HCB$$

I know this is not much, but I couldn't think of anything else. This question will likely involve a construction that I am not able to conceive of. A solution with appropriate motivations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: also consider that $AD=DB$,both are radius,and try to consider  similar triangles

Answer (score 2):

Triangles ABC and DEF are both equilateral. Each side of ABC equals diameter of circle while each side of DEC equals the radius of circle.

Triangles ACG and DEG are similar because $\angle CGA = \angle EGD$ and $\angle CAG = \angle EDG = 60^{\circ}$ so $AG/GD = AC/DE = 2$. By symmetry, $GH = 2GD = AG = HB$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the triangles $\;\triangle ACG\;,\;\;\triangle BCH\;$ :

$$\begin{cases}\angle GAC=\angle HBC=60^\circ\\{}\\AC=BC\\{}\\\angle ACG=\angle BCH\end{cases}\;\;\implies\triangle ACG\cong\triangle BCH\implies AG=HB$$

Try now to prove the middle segment's length equals both side ones'.